# How to generate a permutation of list of lists in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists say

```
[[2, 4, 6], [2, 6, 10], [2, 12, 22], [4, 6, 8], [4, 8, 12], [6, 8, 10], [8, 10, 12], [8, 15, 22], [10, 11, 12]]
```

How do I generate a combination of the lists for a given length?

For example if the given length is 3

Then I need all combinations of 3 list element scenarios from the given list of list.

Example :

```
[2, 4, 6], [2, 6, 10], [2, 12, 22]
```

or

```
[2, 4, 6], [8, 10, 12], [10, 11, 12]
...
... and so forth
```

and if the given length is 2 then it should be like

```
[2, 4, 6], [2, 6, 10]
```

or

```
[6, 8, 10], [8, 10, 12]
...
... and so forth
```

I dont want a permutation of elements inside the lists but I want a permutation of the lists itself.

Comment: Have a look at [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate all permutations of a list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python)

Comment: Actually you want [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) specifically `itertools.combinations(L, 3)` if your list was `L`

Comment: @PeterWood I dont want a permutation of elements inside the list. But i need the permutation of the lists inside the list itself

Comment: @1_0 The permutations are of the lists in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options here. The first is to use [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations). This will give you every permutation (i.e: `[1,2]` and `[2,1]` **would not** be the same)

```
import itertools

lists = [[2, 4, 6], [2, 6, 10], [2, 12, 22], [4, 6, 8], [4, 8, 12], [6, 8, 10], [8, 10, 12], [8, 15, 22], [10, 11, 12]]
n = 3

for perm in itertools.permutations(lists, n):
    print(perm)
```

If you want completely unique groupings, with no duplicates , use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) (i.e: `[1,2]` and `[2,1]` **would** be the same).

```
for comb in itertools.combinations(lists, n):
    print(comb)
```